# How to find what type of exception occur from SQL Server Try Catch while executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, transactions, try-catch

I am executing a stored procedure which has some code inside it and I put it inside a try catch block like

```
BEGIN Transaction Tran1  
BEGIN Try
    //Stored procedure code
COMMIT TRANSACTION  Tran1   
END Try

BEGIN Catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Tran1 
    raiserror('Cannot commit transaction', 16, 1, @@error);
    return;
END Catch
```

When any error occurred it goes to the `Catch` block and raises the error which is a user defined error but it does not raise what type of error actually occurred. So how could I get what type of error that really occurred as we do in C# while executing it from front end like

```
Try  
{  
  //Some code  
}  
Catch(Exception ex)  
{  
  MessageBox.Show(ex.message);  
}
```

Please provide me solution for this

Comment: If it is possible, remove try catch in sp and add in c# code. EDIT : Also add your transaction handling in c#.

Comment: in my case it is possible but still is there any way toi trace error

Comment: Unfortunately i can not help with that :(

Answer (score 2):

The error raised is catchable as a [`SqlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
   if (sqlEx.Number == 50000)
   {
      // 
   }
}
```

You can use the [`msg_id` flavour of `RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) to customize the Number in SQL, or better still, use [`THROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
BEGIN Transaction Tran1  
BEGIN Try
   //Stored procedure code
COMMIT TRANSACTION  Tran1   
END Try

BEGIN Catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Tran1      
   SELECT 
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
ERROR_PROCEDURE() as ErrorProcedure,
ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine,
ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;   

      END CATCH
```